# DataBinding and locking around a list

Tags: wpf, multithreading, data-binding, mvvm

I'm writing (my first) WPF app that searches the web and displays links in a ListBox.  In order to speed everything up I'm using multiple threads to download the links.  However, I've run into an interesting multi-threading dilemma:

Suppose I have the UI thread and then another 2 threads spawned to download links.  Now the download threads add links to a `List` called `LinkList` which my `ListBox` is bound to.  If Thread1 updates `LinkList` then the UI thread tries to iterate over the `LinkList` to rebind the `ListBox`.  If, while the UI thread is iterating, Thread2 tries adding items to `LinkList`, an exception is thrown on the UI thread because you can't add an item to a list while iterating.

I don't want to have to wait until all threads return to bind the ListBox since that means the user has to wait a long time.  Is there a pattern to handle this?  Can I somehow put a `lock` around the iteration on binding on the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INotifyCollectionChanged isn't thread safe (unline INotifyPropertyChanged) so you should use the dispatcher to add items from the UI thread instead when adding items to your LinkList from a worker thread

```
var objectToAdd = ...
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    LinkList.Add(objectToAdd);
}));
```

Comment: Not sure how this helps.  If a worker thread calls the the code you wrote during iteration, the UI thread might still try iterating over the list after the worker thread has already added yet another item resulting in an exception.

Comment: @statichippo: As far as I know, the above code will never result in an exception because of UI updates. The code will be run first when the UI thread is finished with whatever it's doing at the moment, e.g. updating the UI for the ListBox

Comment: @statichippo: No, I don't think so. Remember, the UI would be doing its iteration of the list on the UI thread. `Dispatcher.Invoke` marshals the add operation onto the UI thread so it will have to wait until the previous iteration operation is complete before that `Action` delegate gets executed.